# Invariant convex subset

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, convex-analysis, banach-spaces

Let X be a banach space and $T$ a bounded operator on X with $||T||$ less than or equal to 1. If $T$ is an isometry and $r(T)$<1 show that there is a closed convex non-zero proper subset $C$ of the unit ball $B_{x}$ such that $TC$ is contained in $C$.

I'm not sure what subset would do. I though something like $span(x)$ where $x$ is in $B_{x}$ but that's not necesarily contained in the ball. 
Thanks

Comment: Is $r(T) $ the spectral radius?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This result is true for any bounded operator with $\|T\|\leq1$. Fix $x\in X$ with $\|x\|\leq1$. Put
$$
C=\tfrac12\,\overline{\text{conv}\,\{T^nx:\ n\in\mathbb N\}}\subsetneq B_X
$$
(every element in $C$ has norm at most $1/2$).

This is the most general possible result: let $T=(1+\delta)I$ for some $\delta>0$. A subset $C$ as desired satisfies $T^nC\subset C\subset B_X$ for all $n$. But then any nonzero $x\in C$ satisfies $(1+\delta)^nx\in B_X$ for all $n$, a contradiction.

Comment: What is $T^{n_{0}}$? Thanks @Martin Argerami

Comment: A typo. $\ \ \ $

Comment: Apparently this is true when T is not an isometry and there is no restriction on r(T). For the case where T is an isometry and r(T)=1 one can put C={$y$ in $B_{X} : ||T^{n}(y)||<||T^{n}x_{0}$} But about the cases I don't know. Do you? @Martin Argerami

Comment: You are right. Look at the new answer, please.

Comment: great, thanks Martin

Comment: A typical element of C is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}t_{n}T^{n}x$ where the $t_{n}$ are between 0 and 0.5. I'm not sure how to show this is contained in the ball. @Martin Argerami

Comment: No it isn't. The subset $C$ is not a subspace,  you are not guaranteed that sums stay within. Still my previous $C$ was not convex, and I have edited the answer.

Comment: Ok I have shown it is in contained in the ball by showing everthing has norm at most 0.5 and it is by definition closed and convex. Taking x non-zero ensures C is non-zero. But how would you show that it is not the whole ball? @ Martin Argerami

Comment: Because the unit ball always has elements of norm equal to $1$.

Comment: @ Martin Argerami I was assuming unit ball meant 'open unit ball'

Comment: The open unit ball has elements with norm arbitrarily close to $1$.

Comment: Finally, in showing this is the greatest generality, you have assumed T is a multiple of the identity. What about for non-scalar T whose norm is greater than 1? @Martin Argerami

Comment: What I did is provide an example of an operator with norm greater than one such that the assertion fails, which shows that you cannot omit the norm-one condition and expect the property to hold in general.